# Admob is not displayed during the app's first execution

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I made an Android app with Phonegap (Cordova 2.5.0). And I put admob in my app using [this plugin](https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob).

Admob is displayed in my app. But there's a problem. During the first execution, admob's not showing up. After closing the app and re-starting it, admob is displayed. From the second execution onwards, admob is displayed.

If I don't use the app for a while (about one hour), then run the app, the problem comes up again.

What can I do to fix problem?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You should choose which part of your code is most relevant and post that. The information you provide is very general at the moment.

Comment: The plugin's code looks fine. Are you sure yours isn't any different?